# Adding existing links to custom navigation menus?

Tags: menus, links

When I visit *Appearance → Menu*, I can add custom links, but not any links 
I've already created under *Links*. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add link/blogroll type items to the main navigation - add them as custom links instead.

[Update]

To be more precise, you *could* do it, but you would need to write some code that hooked into the menu creation/editing section, present a list of blogroll links in a metabox, allowed you to choose from them, and then added these links to your menu. Seems easier to just add the ones you want as custom links.

Comment: I suppose you don't know a plugin that does this already? It seems to be such a logical request.

Comment: @jan I did a quick bit of searching, but didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

Under the `Screen Options` tab in the upper right corner of the UI, make sure all boxes are checked for everything you want visible- pages, posts, custom post types, taxonomies, etc..

Comment: Did so, but there's no checkbox for "links".

Comment: ah, sorry, misunderstood your question.